# Loopback 3 app object undefined?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm using Loopback v3, and when I try to reference another model inside
another one, eg. **customer.js**, with

```
module.exports = function(Customer) {

  var Product = Customer.app.models.Product;
```

it crashes saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Have you added a relation between both models? 
Make sure you have defined a relation between Customer and Product models on Customer.json and Product.json.
This can be done manually or by using the loopback generator.

```
slc loobpack:relation
```

More information here: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Creating-model-relations.html